# How to print objects to screen user using Ionic2

Tags: angularjs, arrays, api, ionic2

I have an API with several values inside.
I want to show the values on my screen to the user using kind of label or something.
[Array with objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSDe3.png)

Each object has some values like lat and longitude:
[Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVcK5.png)

How can I show lat and long of each object in a sentence to user?
Like:
"Your location was: + ..value.. + lat and + ..value.. + long

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular2 and ionic2 you have to use ngFor directive to run over array and ionic2 ion-list component, so an example of this could be:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let object of array">

   {{"Your location was:" + object.location + "lat:" + object.lat}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: How do I have to save my array from API local then? I can see them online but can't go through them only with local values of Array I create myself

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat to display list of lat and long and for the labelling you can use [cards](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#cards)

```
<ion-list ng-controller="MyCtrl" can-swipe="true">
  <ion-item ng-repeat="obj in arrays"  class="item-thumbnail-left">
     <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
           "Your location was: {{obj.location.lat}} lat and {{obj.location.lng}}  long 
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>      
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```